# Update a row only if condition is met

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0

I want to update a certain column in row only if row has a valid data. Being specific: I have a table with `Event` which stores `start`, `stop` and `isActive` flag.
I would like some `Events` activate by setting `isActive` to `true`, however I need to check if start and stop dates are valid.
model:

```
 case class Event {start:DateTime, stop:DateTime, isActive:Boolean}
```

my validation method signature :

```
validateEvent(ev: Event): Boolean
```

My first approach:

`def activateEv() = Action.async(parse.json) {
    request => {
 ...
      val ev = db.run(dao.findEvById(poid, uid))
      val ret = ev.flatMap {
        case st: Option[Event] => if (validateEvent(st.get)) {
          db.run(dao.updateActivity(poid, true).map {
            case 0 => false
            case other => true
          }
        } else Future(false)
      }
...
    }
  }`

I believe that it is not the way how this problem should be addressed.
Could you advice ?
Maybe only one db.run will be sufficient ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved in a single `db.run` using combinators (e.g. `flatMap`) on `DBIOAction` objects. Assuming that your `dao` methods look like that:

```
case object dao {
  def findEvById(poid: Int, uid: Int): DBIOAction[Option[Event], NoStream, Effect.Read] = ???

  // In your case `updateActivity` returns an `Int` and you're mapping it to a `Boolean`.
  // That mapping could be placed here, so `updateActivity` would return `Boolean` now.
  def updateActivity(poid: Int, bool: Boolean): DBIOAction[Boolean, NoStream, Effect.Write] = ???
}
```

This is how we can achieve the thing you're looking for:

```
...
val action = dao.findEvById(poid, uid).flatMap {
  case Some(event) if validateEvent(event) => dao.updateActivity(poid, true)
  case _ => DBIO.successful(false)
}.transactionally

db.run(action)
...
```

As you see we have a transaction here, which would make a selection followed by an update (only if the `event` is valid). Moreover, that whole `select then update` action could be a separate method in your `dao`.